# Why does the iron content differ in different species on seeds?

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, seeds

Iron can be affected by pH of the soil but why does each species actually have a different iron content. What causes it? What genes cause it?

Comment: I don't think there is some single omnipresent gene in plants that says what the iron content of their seeds are. I think different genes in different species plays a role as well as environment.

Comment: Why would you expect different species to have the same iron content?  Or anything else, FTM.